# Ionic 3 - Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

**When I'm trying to build an android apk by running this** `ionic cordova build android`  it is giving me an error `Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'`

Recently, I added some codova plugin file, filechooser and filepath in my project.

**Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.**

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>           is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>           Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

**This is my plugin list**

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="1.1.19" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="2.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^1.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="com-sarriaroman-photoviewer" spec="^1.1.18" />
<plugin name="mx.ferreyra.callnumber" spec="~0.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="^2.6.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-filechooser" spec="^1.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="^1.4.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.1" />
```

What can be the issue? please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project platforms/android/app/src/main/androidmanifes.xml file.
then add this line inside your manifest tag:

```
<manifest .....  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
```

after that add the below code after the start of application tag like below

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="25.4.0" />
     ......
     ......
</application>
```

that's all you have to do.....

Answer (score 0):

So, I just recently had a problem like this. And while Noob_coder's answer did help me work around the issue, it doesn't work if you use any sort of automated deployment tools.

Instead, I've discovered that there was a plugin (in my case, it was [cordova-plugin-camera-preview](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/pull/495) which explicitly specified the Android build in the plugin configuration. It needs to use a particular variable and can sometimes be fixed by either submitting a patch or running a previous build.